# Bootstrap's inline form has button on different line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I copied this code straight from [bootstrap's documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/):

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
      <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Transfer cash</button>
</form>
```

I added `width:50%` to prevent the input from taking 100% width, removed the last `input-group`, and I've tried wrapping the button with `form-group`, but this does not solve anything. The input and the button are still on separate lines. I want them to be like in bootstrap's documentation, where they're all on one row.

Looking at firebug, I can't find how the bootstrap doc is restricting the width. Their `.bs-example` class doesn't yield anything:

```
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
background-color: #fff;
border-color: #ddd;
border-width: 1px;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;

position: relative;
padding: 45px 15px 15px;
margin: 0 -15px 15px;
border-color: #e5e5e5 #eee #eee;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 0;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

Yet somehow their doc shows the inline form being on a single row.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5zr4j4mv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Move your button into input-group
http://jsfiddle.net/5zr4j4mv/2/

```
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Transfer cash</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The behavior will be different with varying browser sizes. For instance, if the button is placed in the `input-group` as you suggest, when the window size becomes smaller like on mobile, the `input-group-addon` will be stretched vertically to accommodate the button. In contrast to the bootstrap doc, it will just force the button on a new row.  I would like the behavior to bootstrap's doc, and I can't seem to figure that out. You can shrink your browser window in jsfiddle/bootstrap doc to see this effect.